# PHP: Words are repeating in while loop and group by is not working?

Tags: php

I am trying to display my data **group by keyregion** and then group by **key_region** currently it is working fine for **key_region** but for **group by keyregion** is not working headings are repeating, if headings are same it has to  comes only one for **keyregion** see here [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfMta.jpg)

Code:

**Working of While loop is -**

1. First it sort data with keyregion
2. After sorting with keyregion, it sort with key_region and year and group together.

**var_export for $Zeile**

```
    array (
  0 => 
  (object) array(
     'reisenr' => '2191302',
     'beginn' => '2021-10-02',
     'ende' => '2021-10-25',
     'airline' => 'AI',
     'status' => '4',
     'price' => '4998',
     'keywords' => 'indien24',
     'keyregion' => 'Himalaya',
     'key_region' => 'Indien & Himalaya',
     'Shortlink' => 'die-indienreise.de/intensiv',
     'keycountry' => 'India',
     'tourname' => 'Indien Intensiv',
     'jahr' => '2021',
     'month' => '10',
     'beginn_f' => 'Sa, 2. Okt',
     'ende_f' => 'Mo, 25. Okt 2021',
     'comment_de' => '',
     'tage' => '23',
  )


    <?php
   function ausgabe_einfach($zeile)
    { 

        $i=0;

        while(count($zeile) - 1 > $i){
            global $status;
            $keywords = $zeile[$i]->keywords;
            $jahr = $zeile[$i]->jahr;
            $key_region = $zeile[$i]->key_region;
            $keyregion = $zeile[$i]->keyregion;
            $beginn = $zeile[$i]->beginn;
              ?>

            <table class="termine">

            // Here is heading for $keyregion & $keycountry 

   <div class="date" style="color:#fc453e"><b><?php  echo $keyregion;  ?>&nbsp; <?php echo $jahr;?></b><br></div><b><caption class="date1"><?php echo $key_region; ?> </b></caption>
 

            <?php
            $j=$i+1;
          
           //printing some values here

            while((count($zeile) - 1 > $i) && (count($zeile) - 1 > $j) && ($j > $i) && ($jahr == $zeile[$j]->jahr) &&  (strtolower($key_region) == strtolower($zeile[$j]->key_region)) && (date("Y", strtotime($zeile[$i]->beginn)) == date("Y", strtotime($zeile[$j]->beginn))) && (strtolower($keyregion) == strtolower($zeile[$j]->keyregion))){
    "";

                 //Printing output values here
      like ReiseNR 


                $i++;
                $j++;
            }
            $i++;
        }

        ?> 

        <?php
    }
```

If there any help in resolving my issue that will be much helpful for me and appreciated.

Comment: Please try to reduce your code down to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's much easier to debug when any irrelevant code is removed and sample values are provided.

Comment: @El_Vanja check please I need help in while loop

Comment: Please provide sample input (a couple of elements from `$zeile` should be sufficient) so that we know what you're working with. Tip: use `var_export` on it. Output of `var_export` can be directly copied into an editor to recreate the variable.

Comment: @El_Vanja please check the `var_export`

Comment: One entry is not enough. Can you select a couple of them that would reproduce the problem?